# I'd like to redirect a domain via the hosts file, a bit confused as to how

Tags: domain, redirection, hosts

I have a program that I have lost source code for that contacts a server to check for updates. If the server cannot be found there is an unhandled exception, resulting in a SIGSEGV. I no longer own the domain that the update server was on, I gave it up last year when I switched to a new one.

Let's say this update server domain is programupdate.my-website.com
I want to make requests for this domain go to 256.256.256.4

Could anyone tell me what to add in the hosts file to accomplish this? Also if possible, could I add something to the hosts file that would make requests go to programupdate.my-website.net instead of an IP? With this I wouldn't have to change the IP after my dedicated server moves.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud add to the hosts file

> - Windows - C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
> - Linux - /etc/hosts

the following line:

> 256.256.256.4 programupdate.my-website.com

which would make the local DNS resolver (which has the highest priority) solve programupdate.my-website.com to the IP 256.256.256.4.